# Putting in a list element of a dataframe column with a specific number of occurence

Tags: python

Ho can I extract elements that occur a specific number of time in a column of a dataframe?
I managed to get the frequency of each element using the following formula :

```
df['Column_name'].value_counts()
```

But now I would like to display in the console a list of elements that occur a specific number of time in a column of  dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution. It uses `collections.defaultdict` and simply iterates the `pd.Series.value_counts` series output, reversing the mapping.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in df['Column_name'].value_counts().items():
    d[v].append(k)
```

Now you can easily access, via `d[n]`, the items that appear *n* times.